# Read files from a folder and save it to vector of strings

Tags: c++, winapi, vector

I am trying to read textfiles from an folder and save the names to a vector of strings. This is my code by now. I can compile and run it, but it is not saving my files to the vector.

```
int main(){
Data Dataset;
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
HANDLE hFind;
// Find the first file in the directory.
hFind = FindFirstFile(LPCTSTR("C:\\Users\\bla\\Desktop\\c++\\data\\*"), &FindFileData);

if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    cout<<"ERROR"<<endl;
} 
else{
    while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData) != 0) {
    if(FindFileData.cFileName=="*.txt")
    {
        Dataset.name.push_back(FindFileData.cFileName);
    }
    cout<<FindFileData.cFileName<<endl;
    }
FindClose(hFind);
}
for(int i=0; i<Dataset.name.size(); i++){
    cout<<Dataset.name[i]<<endl;
}
}
```

Any assistance that can be offered is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show struct data and the vector.

Comment: Was your intention to really compare if a file exists called `*.txt`?  No such file can be named like this for Windows.

Comment: change to `FindFirstFile("C:\\Users\\bla\\Desktop\\c++\\data\\*.txt")`

Comment: struct Data{
  vector<string> name;
  unsigned int vehicle;
  unsigned int dim;
  int maxQ;
};

Comment: FindFirstFile(LPCTSTR("C:\\Users\\bla\\Desktop\\c++\\data\\*.txt") is not working. I get ERROR

Comment: @user3264301 **Never** cast string types.  Use the proper string literal type.  You can do this by using  `_T("Your String")`.  The `_T` is a macro that gives you the correct string literal type based on your character set build type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is this:

`FindFileData.cFileName=="*.txt"`

First, this does not compare strings.  It compares pointer values.  If you want to compare strings, then use `_tcscmp`:

```
if ( _tcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName, _T("*.txt")) == 0 )
```

Second, this is wrong:

```
hFind = FindFirstFile(LPCTSTR("C:\\Users\\bla\\Desktop\\c++\\data\\*"), &FindFileData);
```

You are attempting to cast a non-wide string into one that may be wide, or may not be wide, depending on the character set build type for your project (I'm assuming you're using Visual Studio, but it is relevant to whatever your C++ tools happen to be).

The bottom line is to **never** cast string types to fit the parameter type.  Casting a string is **not** converting the string from one type to another.  You should write code that never needs to cast strings -- if you wind up casting strings, the code is wrong.

You can always tell something is bad or needs to be looked at very closely if you remove the cast, and by removing the cast the compiler throws an error telling you that the types don't match (this not only goes for strings, but any type you feel you need to cast).

For this instance, the fix is to use the `_T` or `TEXT` macro defined in `tchar.h` that gives you the appropriate string literal type.

```
hFind = FindFirstFile(_T("C:\\Users\\bla\\Desktop\\c++\\data\\*"), &FindFileData);
```

Last, are you really comparing a file name with "***.txt**"?  No file in the Windows system can be named with an asterisk.

Comment: `cFileName` is of type TCHAR. Constructing a new CString from it and using that to compare might be simpler. I also doubt his vector will correctly copy the string, but we can't see it.

Comment: I changed the code to use `TCHAR` aware functions and macros.

Comment: `TCHAR` is not really the issue. The code is easier to understand without it. The only reason `TCHAR` and `_T` macros pop up in MS documents is for historical reasons and because they can produce one set of documentation for both ANSI and Unicode.

Comment: OK, FindFileData.cFileName=="*.txt" is not working. But how to say if this file is a txt file then do that. I thought "*.txt" was a way of filtering text files.

Comment: @user3264301 Please stop guessing and use the debugger to inspect that file name.  You see that it is the complete name of the found file.  You need to take that name, and get the extension from it to compare with ".txt".  That is a totally different thing your code has yet to do.

Comment: Solved. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code.  Incorrect handling of `TCHAR` data.  Incorrect looping of the `FindFirstFile` data (you are skipping the first file found). Invalid comparison of the file extensions.

Try something more like this instead, especially since you are using `std::string` and `std::cout`, which means you are also using ANSI-based Win32 APIs (otherwise the code you showed would not compile):

```
struct Data
{
    std::vector<std::string> name;
    unsigned int vehicle;
    unsigned int dim;
    int maxQ;
};

int main()
{
    Data Dataset;
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind;
    DWORD dwErr;

    // Find the first file in the directory.
    hFind = FindFirstFileA("C:\\Users\\bla\\Desktop\\c++\\data\\*.txt", &FindFileData);

    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        dwErr = GetLastError();
        if (dwErr != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
            std::cerr << "ERROR: " << dwErr << std::endl;
    } 
    else
    {
        do
        {
            if ((FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0)
            {
                Dataset.name.push_back(FindFileData.cFileName);
                //std::cout << FindFileData.cFileName << std::endl;
            }
        }
        while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &FindFileData));

        dwErr = GetLastError();
        if (dwErr != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
            std::cerr << "ERROR: " << dwErr << std::endl;

        FindClose(hFind);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < Dataset.name.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << Dataset.name[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, you should switch to `std::wstring` and `std::wcout`, and Unicode-based APIs:

```
struct Data
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> name;
    unsigned int vehicle;
    unsigned int dim;
    int maxQ;
};

int main()
{
    Data Dataset;
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind;
    DWORD dwErr;

    // Find the first file in the directory.
    hFind = FindFirstFileW(L"C:\\Users\\bla\\Desktop\\c++\\data\\*.txt", &FindFileData);

    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        dwErr = GetLastError();
        if (dwErr != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
            std::wcerr << L"ERROR: " << dwErr << std::endl;
    } 
    else
    {
        do
        {
            if ((FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0)
            {
                Dataset.name.push_back(FindFileData.cFileName);
                //std::wcout << FindFileData.cFileName << std::endl;
            }
        }
        while (FindNextFileW(hFind, &FindFileData));

        dwErr = GetLastError();
        if (dwErr != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
            std::wcerr << L"ERROR: " << dwErr << std::endl;

        FindClose(hFind);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < Dataset.name.size(); i++)
    {
        std::wcout << Dataset.name[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you have to stick with `TCHAR` data for whatever reason, you can alternatively do something like this instead:

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;

struct Data
{
    std::vector<tstring> name;
    unsigned int vehicle;
    unsigned int dim;
    int maxQ;
};

int main()
{
    Data Dataset;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind;
    DWORD dwErr;

    #ifdef UNICODE
    std::wostream &std_out = std::wcout;
    std::wostream &std_err = std::wcerr;
    #else
    std::ostream &std_out = std::cout;
    std::ostream &std_err = std::cerr;

    // Find the first file in the directory.
    hFind = FindFirstFile(TEXT("C:\\Users\\bla\\Desktop\\c++\\data\\*.txt"), &FindFileData);

    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        dwErr = GetLastError();
        if (dwErr != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
            std_err << TEXT("ERROR: ") << dwErr << std::endl;
    } 
    else
    {
        do
        {
            if ((FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0)
            {
                Dataset.name.push_back(FindFileData.cFileName);
                //std_out << FindFileData.cFileName << std::endl;
            }
        }
        while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData));

        dwErr = GetLastError();
        if (dwErr != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
            std_err << TEXT("ERROR: ") << dwErr << std::endl;

        FindClose(hFind);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < Dataset.name.size(); i++)
    {
        std_out << Dataset.name[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think  the main cause of problem is in this line of code

```
Dataset.name.push_back(FindFileData.cFileName);
```

In this line you push back `WIN32_FIND_DATA::cFileName` property directly to vector and because vector hold address of this property next time you call `FindNextFile` it will override previous value. For this reason it is better to allocate new buffer and copy `WIN32_FIND_DATA::cFileName` to this new buffer and then push this new buffer to vector.

Comment: ok guys, when running the code, I get a list of txt files (cout<<FindFileData.cFileName<<endl;). So my idea was to save those file names in a string.

Comment: The vector holds `std::string` values, not `char*` pointers. Assigning a `char[]` to a `std::string` will make a *copy* of the character data. It is perfectly valid and safe to `push_back()` the `cFileName` into a `std::vector<std::string>`.